# Summing values for each in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a table containing customer ledger entries, where every transaction amount is recorded (including charges and payments). I want to get the balance for each customer in a query probably using the sum function (The sum of the balances gives the balance).

How do i achieve it?

Here is some sample data (I have filtered for only one customer though I have thousands of them).

```
amount  Customer No.
-14,453.00  2709
-12,000.00  2709
-9,200.00   2709
-8,000.00   2709
-8,000.00   2709
-8,000.00   2709
-8,000.00   2709
-7,998.20   2709
-7,997.20   2709
-5,568.00   2709
-4,300.00   2709
-4,001.80   2709
-4,000.20   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-4,000.00   2709
-3,999.80   2709
-3,998.20   2709
-2,953.00   2709
-2,841.80   2709
-2,596.80   2709
-2,558.20   2709
-2,381.20   2709
-2,101.80   2709
-2,000.00   2709
-1,800.00   2709
-1,771.80   2709
-1,737.00   2709
-1,737.00   2709
-1,737.00   2709
-1,736.80   2709
-1,500.00   2709
-1,368.80   2709
-1,181.20   2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-870    2709
-851.2  2709
-820    2709
-816.8  2709
-800    2709
-800    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-580    2709
-571.8  2709
-533.2  2709
-370    2709
-368.2  2709
-356.2  2709
-200    2709
-200    2709
-176.8  2709
-131.8  2709
-41.8   2709
-28.2   2709
-23.2   2709
-2.8    2709
-2.8    2709
-1.8    2709
-0.2    2709
1.8 2709
1.8 2709
2.8 2709
23.2    2709
131.8   2709
200 2709
200 2709
200 2709
368.2   2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
580 2709
800 2709
820 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
870 2709
1,160.00    2709
1,500.00    2709
1,737.00    2709
1,737.00    2709
1,737.00    2709
1,737.00    2709
1,737.00    2709
1,737.00    2709
1,800.00    2709
2,000.00    2709
2,101.80    2709
2,953.00    2709
2,953.00    2709
2,953.00    2709
2,953.00    2709
2,953.00    2709
2,953.00    2709
3,375.00    2709
3,375.00    2709
3,998.20    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,000.00    2709
4,300.00    2709
5,568.00    2709
7,868.20    2709
7,976.80    2709
8,000.00    2709
8,000.00    2709
8,000.00    2709
8,000.00    2709
8,000.00    2709
8,000.00    2709
8,000.00    2709
9,200.00    2709
14,450.20   2709
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `SUM` AND `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT SUM(amount), Customer_No
from table
group by Customer_No
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sum` and `where`

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM table_name WHERE Customer_No=2709;
```

Comment: This will not work since i have thousands of customers which would mean i do for each individually. 
However, this works

SELECT SUM(amount), Customer_No
from table
group by Customer_No

Comment: Definitely a wrong answer! The group by is missing and because of that you will get the sum for all Customer_No. Please edit ..